# How to run Flink job repeatedly with upload jar once?

Tags: java, dataset, apache-flink

I build a Flink batch job .jar package, the file size is 240MB and I have to wait for upload every time I run it in Standalone-cluster.

Is there any way to run Flink job without uploading every time?

Comment: Your jar is mega BIG it's strange. My jars for streaming jobs normally 22.4Mb using Streaming API. With table API it's a bit bigger. Maybe you should check your dependencies not all of them need to be included for execution.

Comment: Thanks Niko, this is a good solution, but I'm looking for some way to avoid repeated uploads, like cache the jar file or specify the path or something. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Speaking of "upload" you mean uploading via web interface ? You can run your job in terminal  like this: `${FLINK_HOME}/bin/flink run -d -p ${parallelism} path_to_your.jar` and you can run as many times as you want without uploading each time.

Comment: I mean upload jar from local to the flink jobmanager, it waste a lot of time, because I run my batch job frequently by `org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils#createJobGraph(org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram, org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration, int, boolean)`